# Implementing Open With action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm creating a Media Player app using Objective-C and Cocoa and I'd like the user to be able to chose a video file on Finder, right-click, select Open With and my app. I'd implemented the Open button under the File button but have no idea about how to implement the Open With thing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Info.plist `CFBundleDocumentTypes` entry is how the system knows what kinds of documents your app can open.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685