# How can I add my Mac app to Open with menu?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am developing a Mac photo editing app. 
How can I add my app to "Open with" menu for images?
Thanks!

Comment: This _might_ be helpful https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Open With action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585673/implementing-open-with-action)