# How can I add my own app to the menu list when click the menu of "Open With" with markdown file

Tags: xcode, macos, markdown

I'm writing a markdown editor on macOS with SwiftUI. I find when I right click any md file, "Open with" list has not my own app. How can I add my own app to the list with markdown file?

(My Xcode version: v13.4.1 and deployment target is macOS 12)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing Open With action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585673/implementing-open-with-action)

Comment: It's a similar question, and I have solved it via the config of `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in `info.plist`.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the question by myself. We should update `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in  `info.plist`, such as:

```
......
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>Markdown</string>
            <string>md</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Markdown</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.xxxx.xxxx</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSUbiquitousDocumentUserActivityType</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).example-document</string>
    </dict>
</array>
......
```